# how can i remove refresh page confirmation popup in javascript?

Tags: javascript

anyone know how can i remove the refresh page confirmation popup from below code.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return "Your files are not completely uploaded...";
  if(is_streaming){
    endStream('Yes');
  }

  if(viewStreamId != 0 && !is_streaming){
    var leaveData = user_info.id+','+user_info.first_name+','+user_info.profile_photo+','+viewStreamId;   
    $.get( request_source()+'/live.php', {action: 'leave', query: leaveData} );    
  }

};
```

Comment: Have you tried commenting out lines of code until you solved the problem?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `return`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line; you can remove it to remove the popup:

```
return "Your files are not completely uploaded...";
```

`onbeforeunload` has browser-specific behavior, but I just tested in Chrome that this line is what displays the popup. Also, by returning early, this line skips the rest of the function!